# Playing Video (with audio; from asset) and recording video and audio (from front camera)?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I do not know if is this possible, but I have a problem achieving this.

I have `UIView` (VideoView) who has `AVPlayerLayer`, and plays some video from assets and has its own audio.

Over this view, have another (smaller) UIView (CameraView) who have:

- AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer (show front camera)
- AVCaptureSession
- AVCaptureDevice
- AVAudioSession

to show a preview of the user front camera and record audio & video from self.

And run at the same time. Similar to FaceTime Call.

`AVAudioSession` in `CameraView` is set up something like this:

```
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
do {
  if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
     try audioSession.setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .spokenAudio, policy: AVAudioSession.RouteSharingPolicy.default, options: [.duckOthers])
  } else {
    try audioSession.setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .spokenAudio)
  }
  try audioSession.setActive(true)
} catch let error {
  print("Audio setup error", #file, #function, #line, error.localizedDescription)
}
```

But still, I have some kind of echo in the recorded video (recorded by CameraView) from playing video (VideoView).

I already try to save audio separately but the problem is the same.
This is my first AV* app, and I do not have so much experience with audio/video at all.
Could someone point me where is my errors or point in the right direction...

[image: Sample Screenshot]

**VideView.swift**

```
protocol VideoViewDelegate {
    func didEndVideo()
    func didEndVideo(of instance: VideoView)
    func isVideoReady()
}

class VideoView: UIView {
    
    var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer?
    var player: AVPlayer?
    var isLoop: Bool = false
    
    var delegate: VideoViewDelegate!
    
    var observer: NSKeyValueObservation?
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = .black
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
    
    func ply(for url: URL) {
        player = AVPlayer(url: url)
        playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        playerLayer?.frame = bounds
        playerLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        
        if let playerLayer = self.playerLayer {
            layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
        }
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(reachTheEndOfTheVideo), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: self.player?.currentItem)
    }
    
    func prepare(url: URL) {
        player?.replaceCurrentItem(with: AVPlayerItem(url: url))
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(reachTheEndOfTheVideo), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: self.player?.currentItem)
    }
    
    func destroyMe() {
        stop()
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
        observer?.invalidate()
    }
    
    func play() {
        if player?.timeControlStatus != AVPlayer.TimeControlStatus.playing {
            player?.play()
        }
    }
    
    func pause() {
        player?.pause()
    }
    
    func stop() {
        player?.pause()
        player?.seek(to: CMTime.zero)
    }
    
    @objc
    func reachTheEndOfTheVideo(_ notification: Notification) {
        if isLoop {
            player?.pause()
            player?.seek(to: CMTime.zero)
            player?.play()
        } else {
            player?.pause()
            player?.seek(to: CMTime.zero)
            
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) { [weak self] in
                self!.transform = .identity
            }
            if delegate != nil { delegate.didEndVideo() }
            if delegate != nil { delegate.didEndVideo(of: self) }
        }
    }
}
```

and,

**CameraView.swift**

```
final class CameraView: UIView {
    
    private lazy var videoDataOutput: AVCaptureVideoDataOutput = {
        let v = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
        v.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true
        v.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: videoDataOutputQueue)
        v.connection(with: .video)?.isEnabled = true
        return v
    }()
    
    private lazy var session: AVCaptureSession = {
        let s = AVCaptureSession()
        s.sessionPreset = .hd1280x720 //.cif352x288 //.vga640x480
        s.automaticallyConfiguresApplicationAudioSession = false
        return s
    }()
    
    
    private lazy var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer = {
        let l = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session)
        l.videoGravity = .resizeAspect
        return l
    }()
    
    private let videoDataOutputQueue: DispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "\(Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier ?? "").videoDataOutputQueue")
    private let captureDevice: AVCaptureDevice? = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .front)
    private let audioCaptureDevice: AVCaptureDevice? = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .audio)
    private var audioSession: AVAudioSession!
    
    var movieOutput = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()
    
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    private func commonInit() {
        contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        beginSession()
    }
    
    private func beginSession() {
        do {
            guard let captureDevice = captureDevice else { return }
            guard let audioCaptureDevice = audioCaptureDevice else { return }
            
            let deviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)
            if session.canAddInput(deviceInput) {
                session.addInput(deviceInput)
            }
            
            
            let aDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: audioCaptureDevice)
            
            audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
            do {
                if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
                    try audioSession.setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .spokenAudio, policy: AVAudioSession.RouteSharingPolicy.default, options: [.duckOthers])
                } else {
                    try audioSession.setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .spokenAudio)
                }
                try audioSession.setActive(true)
            } catch let error {
                print("Audio setup error", #file, #function, #line, error.localizedDescription)
            }
            
            if session.canAddInput(aDeviceInput) {
                session.addInput(aDeviceInput)
            }
            
            if session.canAddOutput(videoDataOutput) {
                session.addOutput(videoDataOutput)
            }
            
            layer.masksToBounds = true
            layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
            previewLayer.frame = bounds
            
            session.addOutput(movieOutput)
            session.startRunning()
            
            startRecording()
            
            
        } catch let error {
            debugPrint("\(self.self): \(#function) line: \(#line).  \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    
    func startRecording() {
        // FileSys is class that find current working directory
        let exportURL = FileSys.getCurrentWorkingDir().appendingPathComponent("Feed.mov")
        var videoConnection: AVCaptureConnection?
        for connection in self.movieOutput.connections {
            for port in connection.inputPorts {
                if port.mediaType == AVMediaType.video {
                    videoConnection = connection
                    if videoConnection!.isVideoMirroringSupported {
                        videoConnection!.isVideoMirrored = true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        videoConnection?.videoOrientation = .portrait
        movieOutput.startRecording(to: exportURL, recordingDelegate: self)
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        previewLayer.frame = bounds
    }
}

extension CameraView: AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate {
    func fileOutput(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput, didFinishRecordingTo outputFileURL: URL, from connections: [AVCaptureConnection], error: Error?) {
        print("FILE OUTPUT:", #function, error.debugDescription)
        print(outputFileURL.path)
    }
    
    
}

extension CameraView: AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {}
```

Thanks